# Use dataframe as filtering criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I am writing a function that uses a dataframe as filtering criteria for a big dataframe containing model outputs. These are the filtering criteria (as a df):

```
      parameter value
1     alpha   0.1
2      beta   0.1
3       eta   0.1
4      zeta   0.1
5    lambda   0.5
6       phi   5.0
7     kappa   1.0
```

dput(values)

```
    structure(list(parameter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("alpha", "beta", "eta", "kappa", "lambda", "phi", 
"zeta"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 
5, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

And this is how the 'outputs' df looks like:

```
     time        w        x         y         z alpha beta eta zeta lambda phi kappa
1    0.0 10.00000 10.00000 10.000000 10.000000   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
1.1  0.1 10.00572 11.04680  9.896057  9.054394   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
1.2  0.2 10.01983 12.17827  9.592536  8.215338   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
1.3  0.3 10.04010 13.37290  9.112223  7.483799   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
1.4  0.4 10.06377 14.60353  8.489174  6.855626   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
1.5  0.5 10.08778 15.83982  7.764470  6.323152   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1   0.95   5     1
```

dput(outputs)

```
    structure(list(time = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 276.5, 276.6, 
276.7, 276.8, 276.9, 276.961144437566), w = c(10, 10.0057192322758, 
10.0198266325956, 10.040096099625, 10.0637654242843, 10.087779652849, 
-1.71585943177118, -2.04004317987084, -2.56315700921588, -3.56775247519687, 
-6.37643561014456, -13.828470036737), x = c(10, 11.0467963604334, 
12.1782709261765, 13.3728962503142, 14.6035317074526, 15.8398164069251, 
27.2774474452024, 26.3099862348669, 24.8705756934881, 22.3379071188018, 
15.8960461541267, 3.62452931346518e-144), y = c(10, 9.89605687874935, 
9.59253574727296, 9.11222320249057, 8.48917353431654, 7.76447036695841, 
-0.604572230605542, -0.878231815857628, -1.46586965791714, -3.20623046085508, 
-14.9365932475767, -3.30552834129368e+146), z = c(10, 9.05439359565339, 
8.21533762023494, 7.48379901688836, 6.85562632179817, 6.3231517466183, 
42.3149654949179, 43.8836626616462, 46.4372543252026, 51.7183454733949, 
72.7027555440752, 3.30552834129368e+146), alpha = c(0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), beta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), eta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), zeta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9), lambda = c(0.9, 
0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5
), phi = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), kappa = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), ode_outputs..iteration.. = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "2916.2765", "2916.2766", 
"2916.2767", "2916.2768", "2916.2769", "2916.2770"), class = "data.frame")
```

So it should be something like:

```
filtered_outputs <- outputs %>% filter(all rows in column 1 == all values in column 2)
```

The names under the 'parameter' column correspond to column names in the 'outputs' df. I'd like this to be not hard-coded, so that I can feed in any filtering criteria as a df and the function will filter 'outputs'. I'd like to use dplyr or baseR preferably.

Comment: Could you add an outputs example and a desired output example, given the df criteria you've written?

Comment: @s__ added it now

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` to paste data frames into the question so that it is easy to copy and test solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Great; perhaps also the same with the filtering criteria dataframe? Does the sample outputs dataframe include enough  variation in values to test the filtering criteria; from alpha to kappa the outputs data is identical.

Comment: @Peter that makes sense – it should work now

Comment: @NicolaGambaro I am trying to get the ``df`` from the ``dput()`` you gave - but it seems to be misformed. Could you try pasting it again (and make sure the whole output is pasted into the answer)? Thank you.

Comment: @user438383 try now

Comment: Got it. So do you want to keep rows in ``outputs`` which exactly match the values in ``values``?

Comment: That's exactly right @user438383 – making sure that the alphas betas etc in the ``outputs`` columns match the values in ``values`` and extract those rows in ``outputs``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution:

Create a helper data frame by turning the values data frame into wide format, and apply a semi-join to filter by the required conditions.

You could easily wrap this up in one continuous workflow but I think it's easier to understand in separate steps.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

conditions <- 
  values %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from = value)


outputs %>%
  semi_join(conditions)

#> Joining, by = c("alpha", "beta", "eta", "zeta", "lambda", "phi", "kappa")
#>     time        w        x        y        z alpha beta eta zeta lambda phi
#> 1.2  0.2 10.01983 12.17827 9.592536 8.215338   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1    0.5   5
#> 1.3  0.3 10.04010 13.37290 9.112223 7.483799   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1    0.5   5
#>     kappa ode_outputs..iteration..
#> 1.2     1                       NA
#> 1.3     1                       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

So you want to select all the rows in `outputs` dataframe which matches the values in `values` dataframe?

Here is a base R approach using `sweep` and `rowSums`.

```
result <- outputs[rowSums(sweep(outputs[as.character(values$parameter)], 2, 
                                values$value, `!=`)) == 0, ]

result

#    time        w        x        y        z alpha beta eta zeta lambda phi kappa
#1.2  0.2 10.01983 12.17827 9.592536 8.215338   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1    0.5   5     1
#1.3  0.3 10.04010 13.37290 9.112223 7.483799   0.1  0.1 0.1  0.1    0.5   5     1

#    ode_outputs..iteration..
#1.2                       NA
#1.3                       NA
```

Comment: It works and has a more compact syntax than with dplyr

Answer (score 0):

I often find these kind of things are easier when the data is in long-form format - although this is just preference:

```
outputs %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        cols = -c(time, w, x, y, z, ode_outputs..iteration..), 
        names_to="parameter", values_to="value_truth"
    )  %>% 
    dplyr::left_join(filter_df) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(time) %>%
    dplyr::filter(all(value == value_truth)) %>%
    dplyr::select(-value) %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        names_from="parameter", 
        values_from="value_truth"
    )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
# Groups:   time [2]
   time     w     x     y     z ode_outputs..iteration.. alpha  beta   eta  zeta lambda   phi kappa
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>                    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.2  10.0  12.2  9.59  8.22 NA                         0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1    0.5     5     1
2   0.3  10.0  13.4  9.11  7.48 NA                         0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1    0.5     5     1
```

Data:

```
outputs =     structure(list(time = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 276.5, 276.6, 
276.7, 276.8, 276.9, 276.961144437566), w = c(10, 10.0057192322758, 
10.0198266325956, 10.040096099625, 10.0637654242843, 10.087779652849, 
-1.71585943177118, -2.04004317987084, -2.56315700921588, -3.56775247519687, 
-6.37643561014456, -13.828470036737), x = c(10, 11.0467963604334, 
12.1782709261765, 13.3728962503142, 14.6035317074526, 15.8398164069251, 
27.2774474452024, 26.3099862348669, 24.8705756934881, 22.3379071188018, 
15.8960461541267, 3.62452931346518e-144), y = c(10, 9.89605687874935, 
9.59253574727296, 9.11222320249057, 8.48917353431654, 7.76447036695841, 
-0.604572230605542, -0.878231815857628, -1.46586965791714, -3.20623046085508, 
-14.9365932475767, -3.30552834129368e+146), z = c(10, 9.05439359565339, 
8.21533762023494, 7.48379901688836, 6.85562632179817, 6.3231517466183, 
42.3149654949179, 43.8836626616462, 46.4372543252026, 51.7183454733949, 
72.7027555440752, 3.30552834129368e+146), alpha = c(0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), beta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), eta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), zeta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9), lambda = c(0.9, 
0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5
), phi = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), kappa = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), ode_outputs..iteration.. = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "2916.2765", "2916.2766", 
"2916.2767", "2916.2768", "2916.2769", "2916.2770"), class = "data.frame")

filter_df = fread('      parameter value
1     alpha   0.1
2      beta   0.1
3       eta   0.1
4      zeta   0.1
5    lambda   0.5
6       phi   5.0
7     kappa   1.0') %>% dplyr::select(-V1)
```